# View dosn't starts from the top

Tags: objective-c, view, scrollview

I got problem with my scrollview in xcode. When I'm puttin this in the view, the contents, right now a imageview dosn't start from the top. There's a empty room between the navbar and the imageview, why? Cant find the problem..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [self.myScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.myScrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, 800))];


}
```

Greatful for help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your view controller, try setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to NO